# How to use selfbuilt android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I have built android from source with this [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) and soon I got a generic full-eng build. It also launching in emulator. Now I need to use this android distributive for testing any specific software.

I also have customized eclipse for working with android `SDK` and `AVD`; and those are working well too. But I need to change usable android virtual device to self-built android. I didn't find the necessary settings in **AVD manager**.

How to do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

1) Create in **AVD manager** new device with same API with as your self-built project is.
2) Go to ./out/target/product/$device/
 
3) Copy next files: hardware-qemu,ramdisk.img, system.img, userdata.img, userdata-qemu.img
4) Go to ~/.android/($device that we have created in step 1) and paste just copied files.
5) Now you can test your eclipse projects on self-built android.